# Cassandra PHP Lag on AWS server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, cassandra

I currently have 2 AWS server as part of my staging setup to run Cassandra read/writes. The Datacenters are US-EAST and EU-WEST. Each data center has only 1 node (I am aware that this is not the ideal setup and I should have 3 nodes per datacenter).

Cassandra version is Community Edition 2.1.3.
I have installed the datastax php-driver.

I have ran a very simple "connect to cassandra" script as I suspected a terrible lag on the nodes.

```
<?php
$stime = microtime(true);
            $conn = \Cassandra::cluster();
            $nodes = array('127.0.0.1');
            foreach($nodes as $node){
                $conn->withContactPoints($node);
            }
            $cluster = $conn->build();
            $session = $cluster->connect();
            $session->execute(new \Cassandra\SimpleStatement('USE test_keyspace'));
$etime = microtime(true);
echo round($etime - $stime,4)." done.";
```

I get a 5.0 - 5.3seconds for this simple code.

I then attempted to run this code but with a dedicated AWS cassandra node that we have on production. I get the same 5second boot.

I then ran a test on a VB ubuntu 14.04 with the same set of php-driver to a LAN computer that is hosting a Simplestrategy replication node. I get 0.28 second.
Then I decided to connect this VM to the staging node (I can't connect it to production because my Lan is not whitelisted) - and I get the 5.0 second lag.

Does anyone know what I am experiencing to get this 5.0s connection lag? Is there something in nodetool that I should be doing to check this?